# IsWindows10OrGreater is Undefined

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to detect if the OS is windows 10.i included the header file  `<VersionHelpers.h>` but still windows complains that the API is undefined. How to proceed?

Also `IsWindowsVersionOrGreater(10, 0,0)` returns false. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check your Windows SDK version. `IsWindows10OrGreater` showed up in, I think, 2015. If your SDK is older...

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2017 and the sdk is v10.A

Comment: Under Project->Properties  Configuration Properties->General->Target Platform Version, what is set?

Comment: It says 8.1. Is that the issue?

Comment: It's the start. Change that to one of the 10.XXXs that should be listed and you'll be able to find the function. [Note the first remark on the documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindows10orgreater) because you likely have a few more settings to change in the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user4581301 pointed out i had the wrong sdk version in my Projects.